# Amazon Athena "Error opening Hive split" Access Denied Error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am trying to run query in Amazon Athena from PHP code:

```
    $client = Aws\Athena\AthenaClient::factory(array(
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
        'credentials' => array(
            'key' => '<KEY>',
            'secret' => '<SECRET>'
        )
    ));

    $result1 = $client->StartQueryExecution(array(
        'QueryExecutionContext' => array('Database' => 'default'),
        'QueryString' => "select * from logs where date between TIMESTAMP '2020-02-27 00:00:00' and TIMESTAMP '2020-02-27 23:59:59' limit 100",
        'ResultConfiguration' => array(
            'EncryptionConfiguration' => array('EncryptionOption'=> 'SSE_S3'),
            'OutputLocation' => 's3://bucket_name/temp'
        )
    ));
```

and got this error:

> Error opening Hive split s3:///data-mining/logs/2019/07/12/07/Log-6-2019-07-12-07-35-01-a1c6d0a9-27e5-458b-b72a-8942a6d2b261.parquet (offset=0, length=756977): com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 4A00D465F919D8AB; S3 Extended Request ID: ...), S3 Extended Request ID: ... (Path: s3://<bucket_name>/data-mining/logs/2019/07/12/07/Log-6-2019-07-12-07-35-01-a1c6d0a9-27e5-458b-b72a-8942a6d2b261.parquet

I can confirm these:

1. Same query from Athena console (with root user) can be run without problem
2. I execute query from user which has permissions: `AmazonAthenaFullAccess` and `AmazonS3FullAccess`

Comment: Does that bucket belong to the same account as the credentials? Can you try logging into the console as that particular IAM User and try running the Athena Query? Or do it via the AWS CLI using the same credentials?

Comment: Hi. Bucket belong to same account. I am not using AIM user, i am using "user" with AccessKey and Secret

Comment: I don't known how to run this query inside Amazon console with this user.

Comment: The Access Key + Secret Key your are using would either be associated with an IAM user, or with the "root" user for the AWS Account. If it is an IAM User, then you (or an admin) can turn on `Console Password` in the **Security credentials** section of the user in the IAM console. If you are using credentials associated with a root login, then you would login with an email address.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using an IAM policy associated with the user performing the query that allows operations on the KMS key associated with the parquet files. Even though a bucket may be using SSE_S3, the files may already have been encrypted with KMS instead.

A policy like so:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kms:"region":"account":key/"keyid"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```